# Shell Script Fail on Azure Devops Piplines Pass locally

Tags: shell, vb6, azure-devops-pipelines

I Run a single compile command on azure devops pipeline and it fails .
Same line / Script pass locally on the same machine
Using Azure Devops Server 2020
Agent on Premise

the code is a VB6 compile command

```
vb6 /MAKE C:\GIT\AutoLoaderConfig.vbp /outdir C:\GIT\_AutoLoaderConfig\ /out C:\GIT\AutoLoaderConfig_Build.log"
```

when run from the pipeline i get errors - **errors are random error** below is a sample of one such error

```
Errors during load. Refer to 'C:\GIT\ctlExersizer.log' for details
```

Error: 'C:\GIT\ctlExersizer.log'

```
Line 174 : Invalid qualifier;Build of 'AutoLoaderConfig.exe' failed.
```

No such errors are in the local run

Pipeline is very simple
[image]

Any Help Will Be Much Appreciated

***** UPDATE ******

Did not find a solution for the difference between local & pipeline build
but managed to replace the code with which is compiling on both option

Comment: Are we supposed to guess at the error number. Is this a quiz? See C:\GIT\ctlExersizer.log as the message says.

Comment: fixed , this error is not actual error on local it has no error

Comment: And what is line 174 as the message refers to?

Comment: this error is random - on every build i get different error

Comment: We'll keep them secret.

Comment: No Secret - line 174 : Private Sub UserControl_Resize()

Comment: If this is a third party control, perhaps the licensing requirements (license file?) isn't present on the server?  But it is on the local machine, which would explain why/how it works there?

Comment: same machine run both locally & Remote by agent....

Comment: seeing this q just now, wondering if it was the  exta `"` at the end of the command that made it fail?

Comment: was fixed i took the image before sorry